# Need help in understanding set ordered relationship.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a paper, where it is said that **X** is a set ordered by relation **R**. Any subset **Y** of **X** is then ordered by the restriction of **R** to **Y**, i.e. by **R∩(YxY)**.

I want to know what is meant by this notation  **R∩(YxY)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relation is a set of pairs.  For the regular ordering on the real numbers, we have $(x,y)\in R$ when $x\leq y$.  So, $R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Thus restricting $R$ to $Y$ is the same as that intersection.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy in this restriction.  It just means that if you have a relation on $X$, and $Y \subseteq X$, then you have a relation on $Y$ too.

For example: Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $R$ be the less-than relation $<$.  Let $Y = \mathbb{N}$.  Then we can order $\mathbb{N}$ by the same relation.

Answer (score 0):

$R\cap (Y{\times}Y)$ is the intersection of the relation $R$ and the Cartesian square of $Y$.   It is the set of ordered pairs whose members are both elements of $Y$ and are $R$ related.

$$R\cap (Y{\times}Y) = \{(y_1,y_2) : (y_1, y_2){ \in }R ,\, y_1{ \in }Y ,\, y_2{ \in }Y\}$$